# Can't delete deprecated packaged Custom Object as it has a Flexipage?

Tags: lightning, managed-package, isv, deprecation, flexipages

**Is it true that there is no way to remove a packaged Custom Object with a Flexipage attached to it?** Flexipages can't be removed and the Flexipage itsself can be edited when it is packaged.

[image]

If so, does anybody know why is Salesforce taking away the possibility of cleaning up Managed packages? It worked for the last years. Why does that conflict with Lightning?